# Passing a generic abstract class<T> as an argument

Tags: c#, templates, generics, arguments, radix

I have a hierarchy system of classes :

```
public abstract class AModel<T,U> where T : class where U : class
{
    protected IList<U> _children;
    protected readonly T _parent;
    protected readonly String _name;
    protected readonly String _urlStr;
    protected String _title;

    protected AModel(T parent, String name, String urlStr)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        _name = name;
        _urlStr = urlStr;
    }
    ...
}
```

I use this for 5 classes that each have 1 parent and several children for example :

```
public class Domain : AModel<Appellation, Bottle>
{        
    public Domain(Appellation pAppellation, string name, string urlStr) : base (pAppellation, name, urlStr)
    {
        _title = "Domaine : " + _name;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is very useful for handling tree views

```
foreach (Domain domain in appellation.Children)
{
    _domains.Add(domain);
    domain.SetChildren(ReferentialDbManager.Instance.SelectBottles(domain));
    ...
}
```

Now my issue is I want to use to pass the AModel to a UserControl constructor from my tree view when :

```
private void OnSelectedNodeChange(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    _selectionGroupBox.Controls.Clear();
    switch (e.Node.Tag.ToString())
    {
        case "DOMAIN":
            AModel<Appellation, Bottle> selectedDomain = ReferentialManager.Instance.FindDomain(e.Node.Text);
            _selectionGroupBox.Controls.Add(new APanel(selectedDomain) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
            break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In the APanel I will use the fields from the base AModel class so I need to pass it like

```
public APanel(AModel<T, U> aObject)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _titleLabel.SetTitleString(aObject.Title);
}
```

How do I pass the generic AModel class as a parameter ?

Thanks

Comment: Change the constructor to use `AModel<Appellation, Bottle>` or make the `APanel` generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic programming is used to describe behavior that is interchangeable between types.

To use this generic behavior in the `APanel` control the compiler needs to know what types are used to construct the `APanel`.

If you intend to use several types with the `APanel` control then describe the `APanel` as a generic type.

For a WinForms control you need to change the `APanel.cs` and `APanel.Designer.cs` files.

`APanel.cs`:

```
public partial class APanel<TParent, TChild> : UserControl
    where TParent: class
    where TChild: class

{
    public APanel(AModel<TParent, TChild> model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _titleLabel.SetTitleString(model.Title);
    }
}
```

`APanel.Designer.cs`:

```
partial class APanel<TParent, TChild>
{
    // Change the type declaration
    // leave the inside of the class alone
}
```

Otherwise you need to provide a complete concrete type to the constructor.

```
public class APanel : UserControl
{
    public APanel(AModel<Appellation, Bottle> model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _titleLabel.SetTitleString(model.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so I tried                                                                                               `using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Common.BottleTools
{
    public partial class APanel<T, U> : UserControl
        where T : class
        where U : class 
    {
        public APanel(AModel<T, U> aObject)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _titleLabel.SetTitleString(aObject.Title);
        }

    }
}` but the InitializeComponent method cannot be rendered and the designer consequently cannot be built am I using the wrong syntax ?

Comment: The control is a partial class so you need to change the definition in the `*.Designer.cs`.

Comment: wow nice that works ;-) but now when I try to call the constructor to use the APanel I get an argument error because the arg cannot be assigned :  `AModel<Appellation, Bottle> selectedDomain = ReferentialManager.Instance.FindDomain(e.Node.Text);
                    _selectionGroupBox.Controls.Add(new APanel(selectedDomain) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });`

Comment: the error is AModel<Appellation, Bottle> is not assignable to parameter type AModel<T, U> but isn' t that exactly what I'm trying to do ? I don't really understand why this fails

Comment: You need to specify the generic type arguments: `new APanel<Appellation, Bottle>(selectedDomain)`. This is because the `APanel` generic type arguments `TParent` and `TChild` do not share a common type hierarchy with the `AModel` generic type arguments `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either provide values for the type parameters:

```
public APanel(AModel<Appellation, Bottle> aObject) { }
```

Or you need to make `APanel` generic as well:

```
public class APanel<T,U> where T : class where U : class
{    
    public APanel(AModel<T, U> aObject) { }
}
```

If the panel does not need the "generic" part of the `AModel`, I suggest you make a non-generic base-class or interface for `AModel`, and cast it to that before giving it to APanel:

```
public abstract class AModelBase {
    // non-generic stuff
    protected readonly String _name;
    protected readonly String _urlStr;
    protected String _title;
}

public abstract class AModel<T,U> : AModelBase where T : class where U : class
{
    // generic stuff
    protected IList<U> _children;
    protected readonly T _parent;    
}

public APanel(AModelBase model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _titleLabel.SetTitleString(model.Title);
}
```

Comment: thanks the second solution looks good can I still inherit UserControl to keep it as a graphic component ? I don't think the first solution would work otherwise I need to make as many panels as I have classes and I loose the generic use of AModel. The idea is that the specific classes are used elsewhere but the panel usercontrol only needs the generic fields from AModel

Comment: I can't get the inheritance to work the APanel doesn't behave like a usercontrol and all the graphic linked code in the designer like suspend or resume layout cannot be resolved

Comment: ok indeed I tried just recreating a simple generic usercontrol from scratch : `using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Common.BottleTools
{
    public partial class APanel<T, U> : UserControl
        where T:class 
        where U:class 
    {
        public APanel(AModel<T,U> model)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
` but that still doesn't work so I'll try adding the AModelBase as suggested but what if I need to access the T parent and U children in the usercontrol ?

Comment: The problem is that the forms designer can't create an instance of a generic type when it doesn't know what the type parameters are. You could probably get it working at runtime, just no designer support.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The designer does support generics. crazyghandi needs to update the type declaration in the `APanel.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: @Romoku the usercontrol works with your correction but the call to APanel throws an error  AModel<Appellation, Bottle> is not assignable to parameter type AModel<T, U> is this normal ? AModel<Appellation, Bottle> selectedDomain = ReferentialManager.Instance.FindDomain(e.Node.Text); _selectionGroupBox.Controls.Add(new APanel(selectedDomain) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });